# Symfony2 - Creating a message forum

Tags: symfony, message, forum, messageboard

I am creating simple message forum for practice, but would like to solicit some guidance on how to setup the 'reply' to Post entity.

Presently, I have the Category (OneToMany/ManyToOne with post), User (OneToMany/ManyToOne with post), Post (ManytoOne to Category and User) entities.

**Question:**

My question is how would I go about setting up an entity for the 'replies' to the Post entity?

Can someone provide a simple example on how I would go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think if there's need to reinvent the wheel. Use [FOSMessageBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle) to handle messaging. If you don't want to use their bundle you can just look at their code, which is a pretty good example IMO

Comment: Yeah I was looking at other forum bundles from github as I'm looking for a simple solution.